# django error "The value of 'fieldsets[0][1]' must contain the key 'fields'." when trying link model to admin panel

Tags: django

I am trying to hook up Django admin panel to a model using the following code in admin.py. But I got this error:

```
"SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'entries.admin.EntryAdmin'>: (admin.E011) The value of 'fieldsets[0][1]' must contain the key 'fields'.
<class 'entries.admin.EntryAdmin'>: (admin.E011) The value of 'fieldsets[1][1]' must contain the key 'fields'."
```

My code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Entry

# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Entry)
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Regular Expressions',
        {'feilds' : ['pattern', 'test_string', 'user']}),
        ('Other Information',
        {'feilds' : ['user', 'date_added']}),
    ]

    list_display = ['pattern', 'test_string', 'user']

    list_filter = ['user']

    search_fields = ['test_string']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. `fieldsets[0][1]` is a dict and it must contain a key called `fields`.

You've got a spelling mistake at `feilds`. It should be **`fields`** (note the positions of `i` and `e`).

Comment: it worked after i adjust feilds into fields, thanks alot!